# Understanding the step in given algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, algorithm-design

I am a newbie to the world of algorithms design and currently working on a algorithm which is related to **cell-phone user associating** with **cell-phone tower**. Let $\mathcal{K} = \{1,\dots,K\}$ be set of cell-phone users and $\mathcal{J} = \{1,\dots,J\}$ be set of cell-phone towers. Let $k$ and $j$ be index of cell-phone users and cell-phone towers respectively.

One of the step of this algorithm is to start with a **random feasible initial** activation vector $\beta$, where each element of $\beta$ is index of cell-phone tower to whom cell-phone user $k$ is associated.

I completely understood that length of vector $\beta$ will be $K$ and it will contain the various values of $j$.

But, my query is how should I initialize the vector $\beta$ in any software say MATLAB if we consider for e.g., $K = 20$ and $J =3$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  If you're asking how to inititialize a variable in Matlab, that is off-topic here.  If you're asking what a specific algorithm does, I can't tell what algorithm you have in mind; presumably you look at what it tells you to do.  If you are asking for us to design an algorithm, it's unclear what the constraints are.

Comment: Thank u sir for the response...by this question I mean to ask the following: Say I have the case where there are 20 users and 3 towers, then I have to randomly initialize the vector $\beta$ that has index of the towers. So, since its random means we can choose any thing which is feasible. So, now if I choose that my first 10 users will connect to tower 1 , next 4 users to tower 2 and remaining 6 to tower 3 then can I say that my vector $\beta = \{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3\}$. Is this representation correct sir?

Comment: Phones usually connect to the tower with the strongest signal that had available capacity and don’t care about any other phones.

Comment: Yes sir....I agree with u...I am just considering initial random step as given in the paper...

Comment: @chaaru What paper are you referring to?

Comment: "Load Balancing User Association in Millimeter Wave MIMO Networks" This is the paper sir..